# Gatling Scala - how to query within session attribute

Tags: scala, gatling

I have this code:

- if I will debug "getSuAndSave" within the session I will get:
  List["a", "b"]

  .exec(session => {
  val getSuAndSave  = session(InfraExecConstants.getSuAndSave).as[Vector[String]].toList
  session.set("getSuAndSave", getSuAndSave)
  }).repeat(1) {
  exec(session => {
  val maps = session("getSuAndSave")
  session
  })
  }

BUT when I am debugging "maps" that gets session("getSuAndSave") I am getting session Attribute

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip2N2.png)

how to query elements within the session attribute?

Thanks

Comment: Piece of advice: you should validate answers to your previous questions and say thanks if you want people to keep on helping you here.

Comment: Sure, correct! Thanks!

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers